# API stops responding when loaded with calls by JMeter

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, hikaricp

When loadtesting using Jmeter, the app crashes wherever it was given a load more than of 55 calls per seconds. Up-to 55 calls per second is working fine.

Application is running on top of undertow server uses RDS Postgres (max connections 800+) for database and developed on top of Spring Boot (monolithic app).

- Technologies
- Springboot starter web
- Springboot starter JPA
- Docker container (separate for BE and FE)
- Hikari CP for Connection pool
- Web server is Linux EC Instance with 16Gb of RAM and 4 vCPUs RDS is 8Gb , 2 VCPUs

How can we troubleshoot?

The app doesn't crash, it just hangs. Stops responding to queries.

we can just restart the backend container to bring it back app.

Frontend container works fine and keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take application [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump), it will show why it hangs
2. Take a look at application and operating system logs
3. Examine [operating system metrics like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
4. Examine [JMX metrics](https://www.baeldung.com/java-management-extensions) of your application and look for heap usage, number of loaded classes, number of garbage collections
5. Use a profiler tool like YourKit or JProfiler to see if you can figure out anything from there
6. Inspect your database for [slow query log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314657/how-to-get-slow-query-on-postgresql) and [deadlocks](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-understanding-deadlocks/)